# What is Logically and semantically correct, A-grade browsers compatible and W3C valid way to clear float?

Tags: css, xhtml, w3c, web-standards, semantic-markup

What is Logically correct and W3C valid way to clear float?

1. `zoom:1` is not valid by W3C and IE8 don't have hash layout problem
2. `overflow:hidden` and `overflow:hidden`
   were not made to do this,as the spec
   intended overflow to be used
3. `<div class="clear"/>` is not
   semantically correct and i don't want to add extra markup.
4. clearfix hack generates content that
   really hasn’t any semantic value.

I've asked many questions and read many articles on this issue but haven't find best way.

Comment: **Logically correct and W3C valid way** and **compatible with IE6** is kind of an impossible requirement...

Answer (score 1):

Using a [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html)

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

Comment: it gives Parse Error *emphasized text*  in W3C validation

Comment: "Congratulations! No Error Found.". It's valid

Comment: What does last part? and is your solution compatible with IE6 ,7, 8 and latest firefox, safari (MAC and windows, Google Chrome and opera)?

Comment: It's just an example of clearfix. It's hacky to handle IE and co and I'm not sure how it works but it works. There are a lot of variations on the subject ( http://bytesizecss.com/blog/post/the-clear-fix ). Consider googling "css clearfix" and see if one fits better for you

Comment: this method generates content that really hasn’t any semantic value.

Comment: Your hack would be better placed in a IE-only CSS (e.g., http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Answer (score 1):

> `<div class="clear"/>` is not semantically correct and i don't want to add extra markup.

That's why often a `<br class="clear">` is been used. You basically want to have a **linebreak** between the float and the next element. True, it's not nice in the markup, but that's the payoff of using floats.

Alternatively you can also just set a `clear: both;` on the subsequent block element which you'd like to put in the next line.